# Delete last 5 symbols

Tags: python, dictionary

This programm must output stroke from list of items.
For example:
Input --> [cow, apple, pig, cow, cow]
Output --> 3 cow and 1 apple and 1 pig

```
def count_things(text):
    a = {}
    for i in text:
        if i in a:
            a[i] += 1
        else:
            a[i] = 1

    text = ''

    for i in a:
        if a[i] > 1:
            text += str(a[i]) + ' ' + str(i) + 's and '
        else:
            text += str(a[i]) + ' ' + str(i) + ' and '

    return text[:-5]
```

I want to output line without using '[:-5]' from the last line (so I need to not write ' and ' at the end).
How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "stroke"?

Comment: @jarmod stroke == line or statement

Comment: The question is unclear. Please reframe the question

Comment: The input should be a string list (e.g.: "cow, apple, cow,..")?

Comment: Note that in English, the output would be written "3 cows, 1 apple, and 1 pig".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this want you want?

```
from collections import Counter

stuff = ["cow", "apple", "pig", "cow", "cow"]
print(" and ".join([f"{v} {k + 's' if v > 1 else k}" for k, v in Counter(stuff).items()]))
```

Output:

```
3 cows and 1 apple and 1 pig
```

Comment: This doesn't add the plural "s" when the count is more than 1.

Comment: @Barmar now it does.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do concatenation in the loop. Put each item in a list, and then use `join()` to combine them.

You can also use the `items()` method to extract the animal name and count directly into variables.

```
words = []
for animal, count in a.items()
    if count > 1:
        animal += "s"
    words.append(f"{count} {animal}"
return " and ".join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **Barmar** and **baduker**'s responses show a better approach. Wanting to use your code, if the input is a string with a comma-separated list of words, what you need to do is split the string by `","`:

```py
def count_things(text):
    a = {}
    for i in text.split(","):
        if i in a:
            a[i] += 1
        else:
            a[i] = 1

    text = ''

    for i in a:
        if a[i] > 1:
            text += str(a[i]) + ' ' + str(i) + 's and '
        else:
            text += str(a[i]) + ' ' + str(i) + ' and '

    return text[:-4]
```

and:

```py
print(count_things("cow, apple, pig, cow, cow"))
```

should now return:

```
1 cow and 1  apple and 1  pig and 2  cows
```

Answer (score -1):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) should do exactly what you want. It takes an iterable and gives you a dictionary of unique items as keys and the values are the number of times that item was found.

Comment: The question is about how to create the sentence with `and` between each item, not how to do the counting.

Comment: Good call, the input/output at the top of the question got me.